# php DOM changes not saving

Tags: php, html

I use PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser to open my html file, I then change the src of all images and save. My echo shows the changes but no actual src changes occur to my html file. Here is my code and I use xamp to test my code.

```
<?php
include_once'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html('index.html');
$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  $node->setAttribute('src', 'images/jelly.png');
}
$dom->save('index.html');
echo $dom->saveHTML();

exit;
```

What could cause my changes to not save? If you says permissions I set all 4 options of accessing on the files properties to write ie: system, auth users, admin and users as already with no luck.

Comment: This doesn't change the DOM it modifies the HTML

Comment: Thank you I get that now. (New to all of this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to [the documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), it should be more like so:

```
<?php
include_once'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html('index.html');
foreach ($html->find('img') as $element) {
    $element->src = 'images/jelly.png';
}

$html->save('index.html');
echo $html;
```

Comment: Haha Thank you it saved, it also wiped my hmtl file haha. But thank you I will now work on why it wiped.